# Python matplotlib.pyplot: contourf not filling contours

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

For some reason plt.contourf() doesn't fill all of the contours and I am not sure why. I am including an example image as well as the code that I used. The values in the array are clearly non-zero, based on the coloration of the different contours.

If you are attempting to replicate what I did, just plot the R_mesh and Z_mesh values  that I have stored below against the total_mesh, also below. For the copy-pasted values, I set num_points = 5.

[image]

Code:

```
temp = np.linspace(0,len(R), len(R))
num_points = 70
temp2 = np.linspace(0,len(R), num_points)

f_R = interp.interp1d(temp, R)
f_Z = interp.interp1d(temp, Z)

R_temp = f_R(temp2)
Z_temp = f_Z(temp2)


R_mesh = [[231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155], [231.36326708, 228.22041934, 225.7332625, 223.9236602, 222.80811238, 222.39706829, 222.69442904, 223.69736472, 225.39646648, 227.77614155]]


Z_mesh = [[-10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617, -10.74879617], [-12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793, -12.2341793], [-13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243, -13.71956243], [-15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555, -15.20494555], [-16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868, -16.69032868], [-18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118, -18.1757118], [-19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493, -19.66109493], [-21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806, -21.14647806], [-22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118, -22.63186118], [-24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431, -24.11724431]]

total_mesh = [[443525976000.0, 726624695000.0, 1307636750000.0, 1837400730000.0, 2149318530000.0, 2255251870000.0, 2179162300000.0, 1903030960000.0, 1403447590000.0, 810807871000.0], [384042275000.0, 588119059000.0, 1218735340000.0, 1879272790000.0, 2241213530000.0, 2353911670000.0, 2273490050000.0, 1958881950000.0, 1335662340000.0, 670862437000.0], [385429469000.0, 631960433000.0, 1206280330000.0, 2079009440000.0, 2463818630000.0, 2559578050000.0, 2492002420000.0, 2176489410000.0, 1339675940000.0, 707430099000.0], [415917967000.0, 744072870000.0, 1494588840000.0, 2602253280000.0, 2727994870000.0, 2772722960000.0, 2739901500000.0, 2646824570000.0, 1655310010000.0, 837434984000.0], [444025058000.0, 811311452000.0, 1599395830000.0, 2384680550000.0, 2718265520000.0, 2787833480000.0, 2739579400000.0, 2462543400000.0, 1746689270000.0, 913058853000.0], [454049884000.0, 779496005000.0, 1460757090000.0, 2190762320000.0, 2602642560000.0, 2716485290000.0, 2636494030000.0, 2283728750000.0, 1586273330000.0, 869166876000.0], [448235202000.0, 663488227000.0, 1155199250000.0, 1814741870000.0, 2548788930000.0, 2627440250000.0, 2607477870000.0, 1933324050000.0, 1252215270000.0, 726181465000.0], [443682028000.0, 520393929000.0, 777717300000.0, 1134377890000.0, 1633968200000.0, 1839629040000.0, 1693609390000.0, 1201290180000.0, 832183387000.0, 550194311000.0], [463925106000.0, 427170504000.0, 532339734000.0, 961007635000.0, 1365719860000.0, 1520967380000.0, 1408922140000.0, 1037495090000.0, 583151907000.0, 431157567000.0], [527888343000.0, 448449257000.0, 599414380000.0, 996156024000.0, 1316777310000.0, 1440007160000.0, 1350795600000.0, 1058245490000.0, 656437235000.0, 443525976000.0]]

import matplotlib.cm as cm
rbf = interp.Rbf(R, Z, total, norm=euclidean_norm_numpy, function='linear')

print("computing...")


total_mesh = rbf(R_mesh, Z_mesh)

print("success")
print(total_mesh)
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(R_mesh, Z_mesh, total_mesh)
```

Comment: you example is not reproducible, some variables are missing

Comment: You are right! I just edited the post so it should be reproducible if you use the R, Z, and total mesh values I posted.

Comment: Sorry, but still not working, you have missing commas and additionally variables are still missing. Please double check reproducibility in a clean environment before posting

Comment: In your code `R`, `Z`, `total` and `euclidean_norm_numpy` are still missing